# How to get img url for Amazon links via Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup for Rich Link Previews.

For most sites, I am simply using the tag meta to grab the title/image but this does not work for Amazon images.

What is the best way to use Jsoup to pull these images? I have tried

```
document.select(img#landingImage)
```

and

```
document.getElementById("landingImage")
```

with

```
img.attr("data-old-hires")
```

or

```
img.attr("src")
```

but these don't seem to work for all amazon links.

What would be the best way to get any amazon link to have a proper preview working?

Comment: *Which* particular web page would you like to use for your Rich Link Preview?

Comment: I want it to work with Amazons link like https://www.amazon.com/Accessories-Nintendo-Starter-Carrying-Protector-Controller/dp/B0792QJ28Y/ref=mp_s_a_1_2_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=nintendo+switch&qid=1633995339&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyR1BVQ0w4M0U4V0kwJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNTQzOTQySDdERTEyUDEwUjVJJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA1Njk5ODEyTE4yVDk2STY1RUNGJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfc2VhcmNoX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=. or https://www.amazon.com/AMD-Ryzen-5800X-16-Thread-Processor/dp/B0815XFSGK?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_ea36ff45_60&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER

Comment: My goal is to have people be able to link an Amazon item and a preview with the name of the item/img of the item would appear.

Comment: Amazon uses neither Open Graph protocol nor Schema.org so you can't construct rich links using any of the two standards. You *could* parse the actual product page and look for the image.

Comment: *"but these don't seem to work for all amazon links."* - which link is problematic?

Comment: The method that you suggested generally works but there are some instances that don't.

Book links for instance don't work. Examples would be like https://www.amazon.com/dp/1974725928/ref=as_li_tf_tl?ie=utf8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeasin=1974725928&linkcode=as2&tag=vizmedia-20&gclid=eaiaiqobchmi45qa-igi8wivfihich0cswu5eaeyasaaeglu7fd_bwe or https://www.amazon.com/dp/1947215450/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&ref_=sspa_mw_detail_1. 
I'm unsure if it is possible to possibly grab all or if there is a more complicated solution that I would need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to copy/paste the selector my browser suggested once I navigated to the image. Based on your examples, the suggestion was either `#landingImage` or `#imgBlkfront`.

Those selectors are obviously too specific and do not reflect the general Amazon product page layout.

After more research, I've found the following structure:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<div id="main-image-container">
  <!-- ... -->
    <img src="the url you are looking for">
<!-- ... -->
```

The appropriate selector for your image would then look like so:

```
div#main-image-container img
```

But in some cases (for example: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1947215450](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1947215450)), this results in two images per query, where the first image is not the actual product image but instead, a "Look inside" tag.

You can edit your selector to account for that:

```
div#main-image-container img:not(#sitbLogoImg)
```

or simply, select the last image of the result.

Final result:

```
// your amazon product page link
// String url = ...

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
```

---

**EDIT**

What seems to be the issue? Every link you've posted so far works for me. Specifically, this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0792QJ28Y").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0815XFSGK").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1974725928").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1947215450").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RRRV5CT").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div#main-image-container img").last().attr("src"));
```

outputs:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81OjP3A5B-L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DYLoyNRWL.__AC_SY300_SX300_QL70_ML2_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51YyZr8Sf+S._SY344_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51OudKdwxDL._SX218_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_ML2_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81IqKdsFOvL.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg
```

Comment: This generally works but there are some links that don't always work with this method.

Comment: @GuNguyen Does the updated answer work for you?

Comment: This seems to not work for every link as there are some without any image in the main-image-container div. An example would be like this one: https://www.amazon.com/quest-nutrition-tortilla-protein-cheese/dp/B07RRRV5CT?ref_=oct_dlandings_m_d84adc09_61&smid=atvpdkikx0der&th=1

Comment: @GuNguyen Are we talking about the same links? Seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: I found an error in my code. Thank you so much for all of your help!